# how to make resque tasks into capistrano recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two resque commands that I'd like to implement into capistrano so I can run it successfully on the server. I've checked by running these manually that they both work, however if I'm to keep these continuously running I'll end up with a broken pipe.

I'd like to be able to start resque:

```
queue=* rake environment resque:work
```

and start resque-scheduler:

```
rake environment resque:scheduler
```

anybody know how I can implement this into my deploy.rb file?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [capistrano-resque](https://github.com/sshingler/capistrano-resque) gem which should do exactly this (it includes support for resque-scheduler).

After setting it up, you'll get these Capistrano tasks:

```
➔ cap -vT | grep resque
cap resque:status    # Check workers status
cap resque:start     # Start Resque workers
cap resque:stop      # Quit running Resque workers
cap resque:restart   # Restart running Resque workers
cap resque:scheduler:restart #
cap resque:scheduler:start   # Starts Resque Scheduler with default configs
cap resque:scheduler:stop    # Stops Resque Schedule
```

(I currently help maintain this gem, so if you have any trouble with it just file an issue and I'll take a look).

Comment: I've spent over 2 days trying to get capistrano-resque to work, and tried a code mentor and was unable to get it working.

Comment: I get no output on running `cap -vT | grep resque`, plus I am unable to start workers. I have posted it under [issues](https://github.com/sshingler/capistrano-resque/issues/112).